# how to get sha hash of previous version, git

Tags: git, revert

I've downloaded an open source code from Git repository. Now I want to revert to a previous version. How can I do that? There is a command like: "git revert , but I don't know the hash of a version, say version 264 of the code

Best regards

Comment: There is no "version 264" in git. Where did you get that number from?

Comment: Probably from an `svn` mindset.

Comment: yes, svn mindset. How to get back to previous version in git please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git rev-list --tags --max-count=2
```

Would also list the last two tags SHA1. The second one would be the one you need for a git checkout to work (and revert the content of the repo to the previous label)

Once you have that SHA1, a `git describe --tags xxx` would translate said SHA1 into a tag label.

Comment: This pretty much answers my question, but one thing still unclear. I know

Comment: @aqavi_paracha not that getting to the previous tag is different from getting to the previous commit: a tag references a commit, and the previous tag can reference one... 50 commits back!

Answer (score 2):

`cd` into the git repository. Type `git tag` and see if the version you're looking for shows up. If it does, you're lucky. Then you can do something like this (I assume the version you're looking for shows up as `v1.2.3`):

```
git checkout v1.2.3
autoreconf # with git repos, this is often necessary before the next step
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

If the version didn't show up with `git tag`, though, then you'll need to do something like `git log --oneline | more` instead and look for the relevant hash id that way. If that gives you too little information, just do `git log | more`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `gitk` to explore the repository along with its history and the hashes for the versions, or for a simple output of the commit messages and the commit hash use `git log`.